# jQuery Slider without stopping

Tags: jquery, css

I'm making a jQuery slider using sliced images to look like one looong sliding banner:

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pG8kt/66/**

Two issue I'm having:

1) The third image in the sequence loads too late

2) It stops between slides - but I don't want it too

Any ideas why? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/pG8kt/76/

```
var showing = 0, // current img
    imgs = [], // all imgs
    $img = $("#gallery img"), // jQuery DOM object
    imgWidth = $img.outerWidth(), // img width assuming every img has same
    $slider = $("#slider"),
    $title = $("#title");

imgs = $img.toArray();
  // Variable to store number of images
var numberOf = imgs.length;
  // set slider width so floated elements line up
$slider.width(numberOf*imgWidth);

  // Recursive next image function
var nextImage = function() {
    var $nextImg = $(imgs[showing++ % numberOf]);
      // Add next image (only use increment once!)
    $slider.append($nextImg);
      // Show image title
    $title
        .html($nextImg.attr("title"))
        .attr("href", $nextImg.attr("src"));        
      // Animate the slider
    $slider.animate({
        left: '-='+imgWidth
    }, 8000, 'linear', function() {
          // Reset CSS
        $slider.css("left", 0);            
          // Call animationg function again
        nextImage();
    });  
}        
  // Call next image for the first time
nextImage();
```

Updated with everything and stuff...

Comment: I see no late loading image, seems just fine with linear easing... edit: ok now I do see

Comment: @Dave If this answer was helpful, upvote it. If it solved your question, please mark it as accepted

Comment: Thanks - this is great. Panel 2 is repeating itself on the first rotation though...